# How is a Python class successfully imported from a seemingly wrong module path?

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

The following line from the *official* documentation of the [Graphene Django Integration](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-relay/#schema) works just fine:

```
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
```

Yet, the class `DjangoObjectType` is defined in `graphene_django.types`, as the project's [source code](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django) may show.

Moreover, running the following after the above `from`

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getmodule(DjangoObjectType))
```

yields this output:

```
<module 'graphene_django.types' from '<myVirtualEnv>/lib/site-packages/graphene_django/types.py'>
```

How is this possible?

Comment: It's being imported by `graphene_django`'s [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/master/graphene_django/__init__.py).

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__.py` at [the root of the package](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/master/graphene_django/__init__.py) imports all the names from types, so you can import it from there.